# I'm trying to change all character within s1 to 'x'. When I run the code, however, the compiler just printed out 'hello world' 11 times

Tags: c++, reference

I'm new to C++. I'm trying to change all character within s1 to 'x'. When I run the code, however, the compiler just printed out 'hello world' 11 times. Why is this happening?

```
int main(){

    string s1 = "hello world";

    for (auto &c : s1){
        s1[c] = 'x';
        cout << s1 << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the for loop you are using, **c** is actually holding different characters of the string s1 not the index of each element in s1.

```
for (auto &c : s1)
```

To actually change each characters of the string use below for loop:

```
for (int c = 0; c < s1.size(); ++c)
```